# scala Hashset contains duplicates

Tags: scala, apache-spark, duplicates, hashset

i have a mutable hashset in which i add elements from a textfile but duplicates are added too.
My code is

```
val machines = new mutable.HashSet[String]

val splitRdd = textFile.flatMap(line => {
val l =line.split("\\t").toList
machines.add(l(2))
machines})

splitRdd.foreach(rdd=> println(rdd))
splitRdd.saveAsTextFile(outputFile)
```

The textfile is:

```
0   0   m2  0   0   0  
0   0   m2  0   0   0  
0   0   m3  0   0   0  
0   0   m3  0   0   0
```

What i get in both the output file and the stdout in spark is:

```
m2  
m2  
m2  
m3  
m3
```

Except that duplicates are added, there is one more 'm2' that doesn't exist in the file. I think that my code is correct, does anyone knows why that happens?

Comment: what is machines? can you update the codes?

Comment: machines is the hashset that m2, m3 are added

Comment: But the output is `splitRdd.foreach(rdd=> println(rdd))`, which is not the hash set, but the elements of the RDD. And what you're saving in the text file is `splitRdd.saveAsTextFile(outputFile)`, not the hash set. So how do you know the hash set has duplicates?

Comment: Isn't the new rdd the same with the hashset? I thought by returning it, it would be the same. Also, i was trying to print the machines but nothing was printed

Answer (score 2):

Well, it looks like you skipped over [Spark Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html) (short, but highly recommended lecture). In particular section called [Understanding closures](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-):

> One of the harder things about Spark is understanding the scope and life cycle of variables and methods when executing code across a cluster. RDD operations that modify variables outside of their scope can be a frequent source of confusion.

Long story short, there is no shared memory in Spark (don't confuse shared memory with so-called [shared variable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#shared-variables), which are, not really shared). What your code does is the following:

- It detects that `machines` are used inside the closure.
- Serializes the value, sends to each executor node, and deserializes to create *local copy*.
- Then your code modifies this local copy, each executor thread working independently of the others. There is no synchronization involved so all you do is deduplicate individual partitions.

Your code *might* work in a `local` mode (depending on the exact context in which `machines` are declared), but in general you should see that the driver copy is never modified and it is empty after your code is executed.

What you should really do here is:

```
textFile.flatMap(_.split("\\t")).distinct.saveAsTextFile(outputFile)
```

This way Spark will deduplicate individual partitions, shuffle the data to ensure that the remaining duplicates reside on the same partitions, and then duplicate partitions.

Take away message here is just read the manual. It will save a lot of trouble in the future.

Comment: Well, i have read it but as it seems, i missed a lot of stuff. I will read it again. Thank you!